# Average, Min and Max of List value

Tags: c#, list, average

I am trying to calculate the average of radius but getting below error:

> Line 136, column 30: Error -
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' Average not define

Any Suggestion to fix this?

```
List<double> arrayRadius= new List<double>();
List<double> arrayRadiusY= new List<double>();
List<double> arrayRotation= new List<double>();
List<double> arrayPositionX = new List<double>();
List<double> arrayPositionY = new List<double>();


double AVG = arrayRadius.Average();
double Min1 = arrayRadius.Min();
double Max1 = arrayRadius.Max();
mToolBlock.Outputs["AVG"].Value = AVG;
mToolBlock.Outputs["MIN"].Value = MIN
Results;mToolBlock.Outputs["MAX"].Value = MAX;
```

Comment: `using System.Linq` add this package in your project. This will do work for you.

Comment: Code posted does not show error you reported. Please check [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post accordingly.

Comment: Works fine for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/clJu96

Comment: I'm getting this now ?     Line 136, column 30: Error - 'System.Collections.Generic.List<double>' ne contient pas une définition pour 'Sum' et aucune méthode d'extension 'Sum' acceptant un premier argument de type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<double>' n'a été trouvée (une directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle manquante ?)

Comment: It seems unlikely you're getting that error now if you've added the `using System.Linq` directive.

Answer (score 2):

Average method is part of `System.Linq`. You need to add `using` directive

```
using System.Linq;
```

Try following code

```
List<double> radius = new List<double> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

double average = radius.Average();
double sum = radius.Sum();
Console.WriteLine("The average radius is {0}.", average);
Console.WriteLine("The sum of radius is {0}.", sum);
```

POC : [Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CKSeHs)

Comment: i'm using allready tsystem.Linq but still getting the same error !!

Comment: Function for sum is **Sum()** not 'sum()'

Comment: @Sater It seems unlikely.

Comment: @Sater, did my answer fix you issue? Do you want me to help more? If yes, Please provide me what is current issue ? Please provide your inputs in **English**